# Translate Vector along matrix in ThreeJs

Tags: javascript, matrix, three.js, matrix-multiplication

I'm using AR.js to track a physical Marker and mapped a square plane to it. I would like to calculate the 3d positions of different sections of the square.

To get the center vector, I took the position vector of the tracking object `AR.js? returns.

How would I calculate other vectors (Black Dots) on that plane? I guess I need to use the `matrix` or `matrixWorld`

[image]

Comment: Note that you can also attach a ThreeJs group object to your marker, and anything you put inside the group are automatically translated and rotated to the proper location. This might or might not be enough for your use case

Comment: @Ferrybig I'd like to calculate it from the center coordinate :)